# Determine whether $f=(\sin x^2)/x$ is (Lebesgue) integrable on $(1,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am given that $\sin x/x$ is not lebesgue integrable on $(1,\infty)$ so I guess I would need to find a connection between the two functions $\sin x/x$ and $\sin x^2/x$.

My guess is that in fact $f$ is not integrable, so I tried to find a lower bound function of $|f|$ which is not integrable, and tried rather obvious $(\sin x^2)/x^2$, but in the end my attempt failed at some stage when I substituted $t=x^2$ and changed integral into something involving $\sin t/t$.

or maybe I could use change of variable $x=1/t$ to convert the function into $t\sin (1/t^2)$, since $\sin(1/t^2)$ is a nice(!) function. But it doesnt seem to work as well.

and now I'm really stuck... I cannot seem to think of any other idea.

Any helps appreciated!

Comment: You do want to look at $|\sin(t^2)|$. This clutters up as $t\to\infty$, and you should try to argue that your integral is asymptotically equal to that of $1/t$.

Comment: Do you mean the function $t\sin(1/t^2)$? As far as I can see if I use $x=1/t$ the domain changes to $(0,1)$ as well, which makes whole thing rather useless..

Comment: No, I mean that $\sin(t^2)$ wiggles wildly as $t\to\infty$, and hence $|\sin(t^2)|$ eventually starts "filling" the space. Of course this is slight nonsense, but you can estimate $|\sin(t^2)|/t$ on very small intervals to see it is asymptotically a constant multiple of the integral of $1/t$.

Comment: Oh right, so it is like $|\sin(t^2)|=1$ almost everywhere when $t$ sufficiently large (slight nonsense, yes) so $|\sin(t^2)/t|$ behaves like $1/t$. And hence not integrable. But How would you argue that rather more rigorously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you already tried this. Perhaps you didn't realize what you got? Let $u=t^2$. Then $du=2tdt$ and $du/u=2dt/t$, so that $$\int_1^{\infty}\sin(t^2)t^{-1}dt=\frac 1 2\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin u}udu$$

Comment: Oh God I can't believe how stupid I am.. Thanks a lot I made a mistake in that substitution